# Google chrome last updated time using powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to get the last updated time for google chrome.

I have this code but it is not giving me the correct time

```
$ChromePath = Get-Item "C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe"
$LastUpdated = (Get-Item $ChromePath).LastWriteTime
Write-Host "Google Chrome was last updated on $LastUpdated."
```

Like for me I have updated chrome just few min back

Please can anyone help me out on this

Answer (score 0):

I think you can look at "C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Last Version" and check the update time on that file.

This also includes the version which you might use to double check.